# iOS 10 : Add sticker extension to an existing Application

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, imessage

I want to make an `iOS` sticker pack for my application.
I've been looking around and I managed to do a sticker app via Xcode.
My problem is that I don't want a stand-alone sticker app. Users will never go to the store to download it separately.

I want the sticker to be include in my classic app, like an "extra" : "You've downloaded the app, thanks you, here are stickers you can use in message".

I've tried to do "Add Target" like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484712/what-is-the-difference-between-apples-imessage-template-or-adding-an-extension)

But when I run my app, I can see my view controller but not my sticker in my messaging app.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Did you check the box that allow iMessage extension from apps to be automatically added to iMessage? It's iMessage store>manage ?

Comment: do you want to add images based stickers only?

Answer (score 22):

If you dont want to use it as a standalone app then you have to use it as a extension in your app.Open File->New->Target and add sticker app extension.Give a name to your sticker pack extension.Also add messages framework in your application.Check in simulator.On device you will be requiring new provisioning profile with the app id corresponding to the sticker pack extension.I have verified at my end