# Upload IMessage Extension

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

We already publish the IOS application, Now we want to publish its message extension. Is this possible ? .If yes then How? Additional question is that how to upload separate iMessage extensions. what are the steps?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i remember correctly, extensions are bundled with the application, so you need to upload a new build of your app which will include the imessage extension

Comment: **Extension** means your app bundle contain it during archive of build. There are two type of imessage sticker app. One is stand alone and other one is iMessage extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible ?

Sure

> How?

Add new extension to your exist project and share it to iTunes. In the new build it will be appear.

> what are the steps?

There are a lot of tutorials about creation of iMessage extension. Try to use them. In several words: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506728/ios-10-add-sticker-extension-to-an-existing-application)

Check [this link](https://jakubturek.com/adding-imessage-integration-to-your-app/) too - iMessage integration to your app

> upload iMessage app seperatly

iMessage applications can be developed and distributed in two ways:

1. As an extension to an existing application:

   - create other project add new iMessage extension there.
   - customize your project scheme and target settings inside one app. In both cases you should generate new certificates and profiles if you want to share it separately
2. As an extension which is an independent application

Comment: Well thanks. Now please if you could help to upload iMessage app separately means it might not be the part of any existing IOS app but user can download it from the App store options, visible in the iMessage app of iPhone. thanks